# Image preview before upload in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, image, file-upload, path

I have this code to show the image preview before uploading it. However I am working with Angular 5 so I have a `.ts` file instead of a `.js` one. How can I do the same in Angular 5? I also want to show the image in all browsers.

My HTML:

```html
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);"/>
<img id="blah" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image"/>
```

My CSS:

```css
img {
    max-width:180px;
}

input[type=file] {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #2d2d2d;
}
```

My JavaScript:

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById('blah').src=e.target.result
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remove `function` keyword.. That should be it..

Comment: I am getting errors such as Property 'src' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' and Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' though my code is same

Answer (score 75, accepted):

.html

Update event attr and handler param for input.
And you should use data binding for src attribute. Following will apply src if it's not null or undefined or hardcoded url ('http://placehold.it/180')

```
<input type='file' (change)="readURL($event);" />
<img id="blah" [src]="imageSrc || 'http://placehold.it/180'" alt="your image" />
```

.ts

In component ts file (class) you should have property `imageSrc` which be used in view (html) and your function should be a method of that class

```
...
imageSrc: string;
...
constructor(...) {...}
...
readURL(event: Event): void {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = e => this.imageSrc = reader.result;

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error -> Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' . Please can you specify the reason.

Comment: If in place of hardcoded url ('http://placehold.it/180') I am fetching placeholder image from my stored icons such as assets/img/icons/camera-outline.png , will the same code hold? I am not being able to see the preview image in this case. Please help.

Comment: @MrinaliniPal if you're using standard angular application generated by angular-cli it should work with local path like `assets/.../.../...`.
Please check you're using correct path.

Comment: readURL(event) {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
    
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = e => this.imageSrc = reader.result;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
      }

Comment: Here's an example with a similar technique: https://www.talkingdotnet.com/show-image-preview-before-uploading-using-angular-7/

Answer (score 14):

I know I'm late but just ran into this problem for both image and audio.  The above solutions worked just fine for images but not so well for audio.  I eventually got it all working by using a URL object instead of FileReader object that everyone is using. 
something like the following

component.ts file ~

```
imgSrc = 'assets/path/to/default/image.jpeg'

imgFileSelected(event: any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    this.imgSrc = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

My component.html looks like~

```
<img [src]="imgSrc | sanitizeUrl"> <!-- using a Custom Pipe -->
```

Finally I created a custom pipe to rid the console of warnings.
my pipe is as follows~

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'sanitizerUrl'
})
export class SanitizerUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor (
    private sanitize: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  transform(value: string): SafeUrl {
    return this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
  }
}
```

To see how I used this for the audio tag you can [check out this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946212/angular-7-trying-to-create-a-preview-of-an-audio-file-before-upload/53959354#53959354)  It's only 2 extra lines of self-explanatory code.

Answer (score 6):

I am using the below code to implement the image preview:

```
onFileChange(event: any) {
this.userFile = event.target.files[0];
this.imageSelected = this.userFile.name;
if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e: any) => {
    this.imageSrc = e.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}}
```

Which works just fine and displays the image preview.  The problem I originally faced was that I receeived the below error in the chrome developer tools each time an image preview is generated:

[image: null 404 GET Error]

Everything worked fine though, there are no other errors.

If I clicked on the null:1 I was directed to the below:

[image: null:1]

After some fiddling and troubleshooting, I was able to find the solution which I have included in the edit below.

EDIT: Figured it out.  I didn't have the || 'http://placehold.it/180'" included in the [src]=" on my component.html. Guess its a timing issue.  Sorted now. no more error.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: Why not? It works for me perfectly fine without any issues. Did you not see the edit?

Comment: Though is confusing that your answer is not complete, then ask about the missing part and then answer it again. I'll remove the downvote but I still feel is confusing

Comment: I read somewhere in rules of stackoverflow.com that they prefer to have edits placed rather than to remove everything which is understandable as then if anyone else is experiencing the same issue, there is more detail around it and how to fix it.

Comment: yeah, actually I tried to remove the downvote and didn't let me until the answer is edited

Comment: @chachan You should now be able to remove the downvote.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What about using @HostListner, since Angular doesn’t come with a built-in value accessor for file input.

```
  @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.files'])
  emitFiles( event: FileList ) {
    const file = event && event.item(0);
    this.onChange(file);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); // toBase64
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.imageURL = reader.result as string; // base64 Image src
    };
```

Then in the HTML, you may use something like:

```
  <picture >
    <source media='(min-width:0px)' [srcset]="imageURL">
    <img src=""  [alt]="Your photo">
  </picture>
```

Answer (score 3):

First we input the image by upload in choose file (imagedisplay.component.html) :

```html
<input #Image type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"/>
<img width="100%" *ngIf="imageUrl" [src]="imageUrl" class="image">
```

Then we use the function for reading and displaying further this is done so (imagedisplay.component.ts):

```js
export class ImageDisplayComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  fileToUpload: any;
  imageUrl: any;
  handleFileInput(file: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = file.item(0);

    //Show image preview
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.imageUrl = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileToUpload);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead

Answer (score 2):

You might just need to change your `javascript function` to `typescript` as below.

```
readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e:any) => {
             (<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('blah')).src=e.target.result 
             //assuming element with id blah will always be an ImageElement
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

That should be it.

**Update**

You can also define a property and bind it to image src and change its value accordingly as below:

In your `.ts` file before `constructor`, define a property as `url` and set its default value to `http://placehold.it/180`.

`url: string = 'http://placehold.it/180';`

You can update this property within `reader.onload` as below:

```
readURL(event:any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event:any) => {
     this.url = event.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Your `html` will now look like below:

```
<input type='file' (change)="readURL(this);" />
<img id="blah" [src]="url" alt="your image" />
```

Comment: Check for console errors.. Do you have anything in browser console?

Comment: you are declaring `event`twice. What's target inside the onload?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao what about multiple attachments?

Answer (score 2):

Kindly change like --> `this.url = event.target.result;`

```
readURL(event:any) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (event:any) = > {
            this.url = event.target.result;
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to preview the chosen image before uploading this code will help you it,s easy. it,s preview only image if anything else then it,s will give you error 
this code is for component.ts

```
  public imagePath;
 imgURL: any;
 public message: string;
 preview(files) {
 if (files.length === 0)
  return;
 var mimeType = files[0].type;
 if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
  this.message = "Only images are supported.";
  return;
 }
 var reader = new FileReader();
 this.imagePath = files;
 reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); 
 reader.onload = (_event) => { 
 this.imgURL = reader.result; 
}
}
```

and these lines of code in component view

```
 <span style="color:red;" *ngIf="message">{{message}}</span>
 <input #file type="file" accept='image/*' (change)="preview(file.files)" />
 <img [src]="imgURL" height="200" *ngIf="imgURL">
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who followed the accepted answer and had `type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'`;  you need to add  `as string` when affecting render result to your image src as the following

```
readURL(event: Event): void {
    ...
    reader.onload = e => this.imageSrc = reader.result as string;
    ...
}
```

}