# How to get selected images file path in Angular

Tags: angular, filepath

Here, I'am trying to get selected images folder path or file path(whatever you called it) but unable to do it,
Please anyone can help me out with this issue that how can I get /access file path as well with selected images.

`<input id="custom-input" type="file" (change)="handleFiles($event)" multiple >`

```
    handleFiles = function (fileInput: Event) {

    const files = Array.from(fileInput.target['files']);
    this.convertImageToBase64(files, []);
      }
```

Please your help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Maybe this question will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482814/image-preview-before-upload-in-angular-5

Comment: thanks for your reply but my question is little different than provided link, I don't want to preview before upload it, just I want to get selected images file path as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. For security reasons, the file path is not actually returned by an HTML input element. Check out [the MDN Docs related to the file input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) for a full list of available properties.

This holds true for any app running in a browser. However, you can access the local file system (and other OS related APIs) if you package and distribute your App with [Electron](https://electronjs.org/).

Comment: ok, but is there any way to do that because we have api on server site which is returning image path so how I can do that, so far  we are using this api for mobile app so I just wanted to use same api to upload multiple images,

Comment: I think I have to change this one api.

Comment: So far I was not using this api I was using to upload single image api but it was not showing  images path

Comment: I'm afraid i can give little advice on how to handle your internal API.

Comment: I'm sorry if my English was confusing: I cannot help you, you are using an internal API.

Comment: Actually I have api which I was using to upload single image but I am pass the multiple images then images are uploading but when I am displaying it, then images are not showing and If I console then I found ` : 0: {image: "http://APIlink:doamin//SurveyImages/d"}
1: {image: "http://APIlink:doamin//SurveyImages/d"}`

Comment: You should not post internal IPs, it may be a potential security risk. It looks like you're not properly using your internal API, but without the respective documentation of that API there is nothing I can do. Additionally, helping with the application of your API is outside the scope SO, please try to contact your internal API developers.

Comment: it's ok, actually you have mentioned `i can give little advice on how to handle your internal API`  that's why I did.

Answer (score 0):

html file:

```
<div>
<input class="file-upload-input" type='file'  multiple accept="image/*" (change)="onFileChange($event)" />
<img className="align-self-center" width= '100%' src="{{ImageUrl}}" />
</div>
```

.ts file:

```
public ImageUrl = "";
  public FileImage : any;

    onFileChange(event : any) {
         this.FileImage = event.target.files[0];
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = (event:any) => {
           this.ImageUrl = event.target.result;   
        }
         reader.readAsDataURL(this.FileImage);
      }
    }
```

add above code HTML and ts file. then you will have a preview from the local path. file here with "FileImage"