# how canIi upload an image using input tag to a angular component?

Tags: angular

I have defined one component and want to upload an image to this using input tag.
The image should be visible like a proper image and not just a file upload.
Also i want this image to be draggable i.e I can position it anywhere on the page.How can I do it using angular?

Comment: What research have you done into this? There must be plenty of tutorials

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: upto now i am just able to upload the image  like this: <input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" >.The image is uploaded and i am able to pass event object to the function File change which is simply  fileChange(event:any) {
    console.log(event);
    }.But i want the image to actually come like a picture proper one not just a file nameANy help or siggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: The top 3 links from my first Google search: https://www.talkingdotnet.com/show-image-preview-before-uploading-using-angular-7/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482814/image-preview-before-upload-in-angular-5 https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-image-upload-easy-with-angular-1ed14cb2773b/ I'm sure there are plenty more

Comment: @KurtHamilton thank you!

Comment: @aakritipriya In future, please at least make an attempt to do some research rather than spamming StackOverflow with non-specific questions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution.

```
uploadFile(event){   
let elem = event.target; 
if(elem.files.length > 0){    
  let formData = new FormData();  
  formData.append('myfile', elem.files[0]); 
  this.fileService.sendFile(formData).subscribe(
    (response) => {
      //response code
console.log(response);
    });
}
```

More information can be found [here](http://frontendguider.com/how-to-upload-files-in-angular-with-laravel/)

Answer (score 0):

Add on html your input. I am using matbutton to replace the default upload input.

```
    <div>
        <button mat-stroked-button type="button" (click)="filePicker.click()">Pick Image</button>
        <input type="file" hidden #filePicker (change)="onImagePicked($event)">
    </div>
    <div class="image-preview" *ngIf="imagePreview !== '' && imagePreview">
        <img [src]="imagePreview" [alt]="form.value.title">
    </div>
```

ts file

```
form: FormGroup;//in case you are using form
imagePreview: string; 

onImagePicked(event: Event){
  const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
  this.form.patchValue({image: file});
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    this.imagePreview = reader.result as string;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```