# image not showing while using reader jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

The image is not showing,,, the code picks up the relative path of image instead of absolute path

```js
 readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result.toString);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
```

Comment: Give us the value of input param of the readURL

Comment: I am reading my local files using the html <input type = file>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small syntax mistake, `toString()` should be called as a method:

```js
 function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result.toString());
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
 }
$('#myFile').on('change', function(){
      readURL(event.target);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="myFile"/>
<img src="" id="blah" style="height:50px;width:50px;"/>
```

Comment: I am using angular and there seems to be an issue if I do not use the .tostring() which still does not output

Comment: Use ``e.target.result`` instead

Comment: it brings up an error... I have checked and the code is not even getting past the if statement. When I remove the if statement I get this error core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: I had tried on a previous project without angular and the image only showed on internet explorer...and the absolute path was shown too but on google chrome and other browsers it did not show

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482814/image-preview-before-upload-in-angular-5

Comment: I had to change a few stuff to get it to work but this worked eventually. Thank you.