# showing multiple images in popup which are already chosen angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular5

I have a table which has two columns namely **file** and **preview**. In the file column I have given the option to choose images. It can select multiple images and I have also written code in such a way that I can also delete those images.

In the **preview** column I have kept button(named View) which opens a modal popup.

**My problem:**
What I want is that I want to show the images I have selected in the **file** column to display it on the popup(which is in preview column) as real images(as a image preview).

I don't have any idea how to preview it. I have tried ngfor but couldn't do it.
Please help me if you have any idea and let me know in the comments if my question is unclear.

**My stackblitz:**https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-modal-input-value-pxfnwe?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer here [Image preview before upload in angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482814/image-preview-before-upload-in-angular-5)
So you should read the files after upload in order to preview them. This can be done by adding the below function:

```
btn(list) {
    list.files.forEach(file => {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = _event => {
        this.previews.push(reader.result);
      };
    });
    console.warn(this.previews);
  }
```

And use previews in the HTML like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let url of previews">
    <img [src]="url" width="150" height ="100">
</div>
```

Updated stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-modal-input-value-nvdops?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I have already found out the solution but thanks anyway(Accepted)